# How to trace the requests entered into the database after pressing a button on the application side in Oracle SQL Developer?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, monitoring

I want to trace the requests of a database when data is placed in the database from the application side in Oracle SQL Developer. **(Actually, I want to see what tables are called in the database after pressing a button in the application.)**

Can anyone help me?

Comment: I don't think that database is aware of the fact that someone pressed the button, somewhere. But, if you talk to DBA and ask them to enable **auditing**, then you might try to trace what's going on in the database once you push the button which - presumably - calls some procedure, and it then does whatever it does.

Answer (score 0):

Client side logs for this are built-into the product. Simply observe the Log panel. Every single statement or script sent to the database to be executed on the database are shown, alongside the execution time (as observed by the client) and any/all bind variable values.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help. This option does not work for me and after clicking on the **Reduction >>> Add reduction policy or Enable reduction policy**, I get this error: **Grants missing on redaction_policies and redaction_columns.**

Comment: Seriously? It logs everything you do, redaction policy clicks, running sql, creating a table, EVERYTHING. The redaction policy thing i showed was ONLY an example. And now using the log, you can see the SQL we ran that resulted in the Grants missing on redaction_policies and redaction_columns error. It does work, trust me.